# Is there a way to make sure my array doesn't return null values, or a way to fix my array so that it doesn't?

Tags: java, arrays, null

I am running into an issue creating a randomized deck of cards. My deck[] is returning null values where cards, such as "2C" as 'Two of Clubs' is returning as null. I know that the indexing starts at 0, which is why you will see "int n=51." My error comes from creating the deck in order of 2's, than 3's and so forth.

public class Cards {

```
static String[] CARD = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
static String[] SUIT = {"C", "D", "H", "S"};

//creating a deck that is in order of C2-CA,D2-DA,H2-HA,S2-SA
public static String[] shuffledDeck() {
    int n=51;
    String[] deck = new String[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < CARD.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SUIT.length; j++) {
            deck[(j+i)] = CARD[i] + SUIT[j];
        }
    }
    //Shuffling the deck
   for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
       int rand = k + (int) (Math.random() * (n - k));
       String temp = deck[k];
       deck[k] = deck[rand];
       deck[rand] = temp;
   }
   return deck;
}
```

public class FiveCardPoker{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(Cards.shuffledDeck()));
}
```

I would expect to see a random assortment such as "[3C,8H,AD,9C,etc]"
but the output I am getting is "[null, null, null, KC, null, null, 10C, etc]"

Comment: Your problem is this: `deck[(j+i)] = CARD[i] + SUIT[j];`. Adding the two variables to index into `deck` makes no sense here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your issues is due to how you are looping through on creation, specifically:

```
deck[(j+i)] = CARD[i] + SUIT[i]
```

this means that you will have repeating indices. For example with:

```
i = 0, j = 0 : i+j = 0
i = 0, j = 1 : i+j = 1
i = 0, j = 2 : i+j = 2
.
.
i = 1, j = 0 : i+j = 1
i = 1, j = 1 : i+j = 2
.
.
i = 2, j = 0 : i+j = 2
```

Thus some indices will never be set resulting in null values throughout your array.

You will need to instead find a formula for i and j that will give the correct index.

EDIT:
also forgot to mention that your array should be initialized with a size of 52, though the last index will still be 51 as you have pointed out

Comment: or just go for simplicity and add an external counter :P ie `deckCt=0; ... deck[deckCt]....;deckCt++;`

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you Morgan and Jorge. Such a simple fix I was over looking. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably late, but here:-

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Cards {
    static String[] CARD = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", 
         "Q", "K", "A"};
    static String[] SUIT = {"C", "D", "H", "S"};

    public static String[] shuffledDeck() {
        int n = CARD.length * SUIT.length; // 13*4 = 52
        String[] deck = new String[n];
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < CARD.length; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SUIT.length; ++j) {
                deck[cnt] = CARD[i] + SUIT[j];
                cnt++;
            }
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            int rand = k + (int) (Math.random() * (n - k));
            String temp = deck[k];
            deck[k] = deck[rand];
            deck[rand] = temp;
        }
        return deck;
    }
}

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(Cards.shuffledDeck()));
    }
}
```